# How much of the Natsume's Book of Friends manga was adapted into the anime?

Tags: natsumes-book-of-friends

The anime series currently has 6 seasons. How much of the manga was adapted into these 6 seasons? Are there any differences in the plot between the anime and the manga?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%8F%E7%9B%AE%E5%8F%8B%E4%BA%BA%E5%B8%B3#%E5%90%84%E8%A9%B1%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88) and [Natsume's Book of Friends Wiki](https://natsumeyuujinchou.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Episodes), ***the 6-seasons of Natsume's Book of Friends* covers up to chapter 79 (volume 20)**, but the progression is not really linear, a few chapters are skipped (chapters 71 and 77; *specials 5, 8, and 14*), and some episodes are **anime original**.

The full list:

- Season 1

  - Episode 1: Ch. 1 (Vol. 1)
  - Episode 2: Ch. 2 (Vol. 1)
  - Episode 3: Vol. 1 (Vol. 1)
  - Episode 4: Ch. 5 (Vol. 2)
  - Episode 5: **anime original**
  - Episode 6: Ch. 4 (Vol. 1)
  - Episode 7: *Special 1 (Vol. 4)*
  - Episode 8: Ch. 10 (Vol. 3)
  - Episode 9: Ch. 7 (Vol. 2)
  - Episode 10: Ch. 8 (Vol. 2)
  - Episode 11: *Special 3 (Vol. 4)*
  - Episode 12: Ch. 6 (Vol. 2)
  - Episode 13: *Special 4 (Vol. 5), some part is anime original*
- Season 2

  - Episode 1: Ch. 9 (Vol. 3)
  - Episode 2: Ch. 13 (Vol. 4)
  - Episode 3: Ch. 14 (Vol. 4)
  - Episode 4: Ch. 12 (Vol. 3)
  - Episode 5: *Special 6 (Vol. 6), some part is anime original*
  - Episode 6-7: Ch. 17-18 (Vol. 5)
  - Episode 8: Ch. 16 (Vol. 5)
  - Episode 9: Ch. 15 (Vol. 4)
  - Episode 10: Ch. 19 (Vol. 5)
  - Episode 11: Ch. 11 (Vol. 3)
  - Episode 12-13: Ch. 20-22 (Vol. 6)
- Season 3

  - Episode 1: Ch. 48 (Vol. 12)
  - Episode 2: **anime original**
  - Episode 3: Ch. 37-38 (Vol. 10)
  - Episode 4: *Special 2 (Vol. 4)*
  - Episode 5: Ch. 42-43 (Vol. 11)
  - Episode 6-7: Ch. 23-26 (Vol. 7)
  - Episode 8: **anime original**
  - Episode 9: Ch. 27 (Vol. 8)
  - Episode 10-11: Ch. 28-29 (Vol. 8)
  - Episode 12: Ch. 30-31 (Vol. 8)
  - Episode 13: *Special 7 (Vol. 7)*
- Season 4

  - Episode 1-2: Ch. 34-36 (Vol. 9)
  - Episode 3: Ch. 32-33 (Vol. 9)
  - Episode 4: Ch. 47 (Vol. 12)
  - Episode 5: *Special 9 (Vol. 9)*
  - Episode 6-7: Ch. 49-51 (Vol. 12)
  - Episode 8: **anime original**
  - Episode 9-10: Ch. 39-41 (Vol. 10)
  - Episode 11-13: Ch. 44-46 (Vol. 11)
- Season 5

  - Episode 1: Ch. 57-59 (Vol. 14)
  - Episode 2: Ch. 56 (Vol. 14)
  - Episode 3-4: Ch. 52-54 (Vol. 13)
  - Episode 5: Ch. 64-65 (Vol. 16)
  - Episode 6: Ch. 55 (Vol. 14)
  - Special ep. 1: **anime original**
  - Episode 7: Ch. 66-67 (Vol. 16)
  - Episode 8: *Special 15 (Vol. 17)*
  - Episode 9: Ch. 63 (Vol. 15)
  - Episode 10: *Special 13 (Vol. 15)*
  - Episode 11: *Special 12 (Vol. 14)*
  - Special ep. 2: **anime original**
  - Special ep. 3: Ch. 70 (Vol. 17)
- Season 6

  - Episode 1: Ch. 78 (Vol. 20)
  - Episode 2: Ch. 75 (Vol. 19)
  - Episode 3: Ch. 74 (Vol. 19)
  - Episode 4-5: Ch. 60-62 (Vol. 15)
  - Episode 6: *Special 10-11 (Vol. 13)*
  - Episode 7: Ch. 76 (Vol. 19)
  - Episode 8: Ch. 68-69 (Vol. 17)
  - Episode 9: Ch. 79 (Vol. 20)
  - Episode 10-11: Ch. 72-73 (Vol. 18)
  - Special ep. 1: **anime original**
  - Special ep. 2: *Special 16 (Vol. 18)*

Answer (score 4):

As of 4th season, the anime covers the manga up through [chapter 51](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=416029#msg13918177), which is the final chapter of volume 12 of the Japanese *tankouban* (graphic novels).

A difference occurs in [chapter 36](http://forums.mangafox.me/threads/487372-Some-questions-about-this-Manga?p=12512848&viewfull=1#post12512848), which is in volume 9.

To date, the manga series has been collected into [19 volumes](http://www.s-book.net/plsql/slib_search?sha=8&jan=&pat=b2&text=%89%C4%96%DA%97F%90l%92%A0) but it is still ongoing in [LaLa](http://www.hakusensha.co.jp/natsume/) magazine. There are also a spin-off 4-panel gag manga web comic titled [『ニャンコ先生が行く！』](http://www.hanayumeonline.com/magazine/magazine08.html)(Nyanko-sensei ga Iku!) which can be read online for free on the official website, free online [novels](http://www.hakusensha.co.jp/novels/), 1 published [novel](http://www.s-book.net/plsql/slib_detail?isbn=9784592197492), and 3 drama CDs (which were *furoku* freebies only available with the purchase of specific issues of LaLa).

Comment: Could you explain the difference you mention? (even if it's in a `>!` spoiler)